# Google Tag Manager passing "undefined" for user-defined query URL variable

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have buttons on my site which open URLs in the following format:

https://www.stackoverflow.com/?variable-1=value-1&variable-2=value-2&variable-3=value-3/

Currently I'm using a tag to pass most of the default click variables for this specific outbound domain to Google Analytics, and to set up a goal. This is working fine - I used this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXONXfZQfFo

What I want to do now is include the value of variable 3 as the event label in Google Analytics, as opposed to the button text which is what I'm doing now.

Following this answer: [How to Use Google Tag Manager to Retrieve URL Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715901/how-to-use-google-tag-manager-to-retrieve-url-parameters) I made a new user-defined variable "Click Referrer".

[GTM variable settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TplBT.png)

However, the variable always outputs as undefined in the console.

[Debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlLui.png)

I've tried:

- Changing the parameter to something without a hyphen, like "value3".
- Enclosing the query key with ' '.
- Changing "Component type" to "Full URL" to ensure that the custom variable is actually being picked up. It is - the issue only comes about when I include a query key. When no query key is given (and component type = query) no output is recorded.
- Trying the query key for other parameters in the URL, like variable-1 and variable-2.

Answer (score 0):

The Variable you set up won't help since this has the value of the variable-3 parameter of *your page URL* but not a *click URL*. You'll need a custom JavaScript variable to retrieve a parameter from what is accessible as {{CLick URL}}:
something like that would work for you:

```
function () {
  function parse_query_string(query) {
    var vars = query.split("&");
    var query_string = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
      var pair = vars[i].split("=");
      var key = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
      var value = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
      // If first entry with this name
      if (typeof query_string[key] === "undefined") {
        query_string[key] = decodeURIComponent(value);
        // If second entry with this name
      } else if (typeof query_string[key] === "string") {
        var arr = [query_string[key], decodeURIComponent(value)];
        query_string[key] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
      } else {
        query_string[key].push(decodeURIComponent(value));
      }
    }
    return query_string;
  }

  return parse_query_string({{Click URL}})['variable-3']
}
```